# How are Black Holes shadow and deviation from circularity measured?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, kerr-metric, shadow

After the images of M87* and SgrA* black holes from the EHT collaboration, Black Hole Physics have entered in a new "astrophysical" era. I've started to read about these objects recently, but I'm not fully familiar with Physics (I'm studying math) In the paper from the EHT collab about SgrA*, they stablish some values for the shadow, $48.7 \pm 0.7 \mu as$, and for the deviation from circularity, e.g., $\delta = -0.08^{+0.09}_{-0.09}$. While I understand the concepts, the idea on how to measure distances is a bit obscure to me.

Also, I do not understand why the shadow is measured in arcseconds, because as far as I knew, arcseconds is a measure for an angle and it is not a distance. So, how is the conversion done? (I assume that there is some trigonometry involved, but I can't find any references with the computation) And finally, for nonphysicists, how big is the shadow of SgrA* ??

Comment: How deep do you want to go on "how are distances measured"? The EHT uses an extremely complicated process to go from the small amounts of data they have to an image, and then a somewhat complicated process to go from the image to numerical values of the diameter and deviation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? It is not my objective to dig into the code, but at least to understand the ideas, and the Physics behind the process

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Sagittarius A* image [[source](https://beta.nsf.gov/science-matters/image-sgr-black-hole-center-our-galaxy)]:

[image: event horizon telescope image]

The light in the ring is emitted by the black hole's accretion disk. We are not necessarily seeing the disk head-on, as if we just happened to be looking from near the "pole" of the disk, rather than from the the "equator" as we do with Saturn's rings. The black hole's gravity let's us see the part of the disk that's obscured by the hole.

The "circularity" is whether the dark region is a circle — modulated by a number of physical and instrumental effects which would distort a circular shadow.

Transverse distances in astronomy are measured in angular units because that's what telescopes actually measure. To find an absolute width in light-minutes or kilometers or whatever, you have to know how far the object is. Radial distances ("how far") are a *very* hard problem. But every observer agrees that a great circle around the sky subtends 360⁰, and so every observer can check an *apparent* width given in arcseconds.